# How to autocomplete enum switch using Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, enums

Let say you have an enum:

```
typedef enum {
    Sunday,
    Monday,
    Tuesday,
    Wednesday,
    Thursday,
    Friday,
    Saturday
} DayOfWeek;
```

when writing a switch statement, a Xcode is trying to help with switch statement snippet:

[image]

and then:

[image]

great, but I need to list all enums:

```
DayOfWeek day = ...; // a day of week
switch (day) {
    case Sunday:
        break;
    case Monday:
        break;
    case Tuesday:
        break;
    case Wednesday:
        break;
    case Thursday:
        break;
    case Friday:
        break;
    case Saturday:
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

Unfortunately, have to do it manually :( Is there any known snippet to populate all cases?
Of course I saw some answers 3 years old states that it is impossible, but maybe something changed since that time? Any ideas?

Comment: Consider using AppCode from JetBrains http://www.jetbrains.com/objc/features/ : `Intention Actions - Multiple intention actions are there to improve your code, or make some routine work easier. They allow you to create symbols from usage, declare methods, swap parts of a boolean expression, merge nested 'if's, **generate switch cases**, and so on.`

Comment: You can't do it with Xcode out of the box. File a bug report and request the enhancement. https://bugreport.apple.com/

Comment: @Jeff you should promote your comment to an answer.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Saw your question and decided to build an Xcode plugin that does exactly that.

Check it out: https://github.com/stefanceriu/SCXcodeSwitchExpander

[image: SCXcodeSwitchExpander]

Comment: I've installed SCXcodeSwitchExpander, but it doesn't work in my case. What I did: Installed Alcatraz. installed switch expander, relaunch XCode multiple times. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 36):

#### Short Answer :

Use `Editor` > `Refactor` > `Add Missing Switch Cases`

[image: Xcode screenshot]

#### Convenient way :

1. Open `Preferences` by pressing `[command]` + `[,]` in Xcode.
2. Go to `Key Bindings` tab and set a shortcut for the command `Refactor > Add Missing Switch Cases`.
   [image: xcode preferences screenshot]
3. Input the shortcut in editor. Be sure the cursor is on `switch` letters.
   [image: xcode gif]

Answer (score 12):

in Xcode 10 do the following

1. add `switch...case` template and set your enum type instead of `self` so that xcode understands what it should autocomplete

[image]

2. move cursor inside word `switch` and go to `menu > editor > refactor > expand switch cases` 
   [image]

This is what you will get as result
[image]

Comment: This works pretty well. I could not find any possibility to create a key shortcut for this. All other refactor options are configurable but not this one. Could you find a possibility?

Comment: Hey @PhilippOtto! I'm searching for a way to add a shortcut for that as well, have you found anything useful?

Comment: @MuhamedAlGhzawi no unfortunately not

Comment: Work very well with Xcode 11.3.1, but we have to put a cursor at a switch word.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately this is not possible with Xcode out of the box. File a bug report and select the request an enhancement option.

https://bugreport.apple.com

I actually did this myself lately, and they gauge the severity and importance of bugs/enhancements by the number of duplicates they receive for a given issue - hence one of the reasons for not being able to search the tracker.

Comment: What's the radar #? Makes it easier to duplicate.

Comment: The Bug Reporter isn't searchable is it? Nonetheless, this the ID of the ticket mine was marked as duplicate against - 9663422

Comment: No, but I'll just file a bug report with body "Duplicate of 9663422". Makes it easier for all of us.

Answer (score 2):

Just hit "Fix" button and the cases will appear:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

While Xcode won't autocomplete the entire switch statement, there are tricks to speeding up writing them. This is what I've been doing lately:

1. Start the switch autocomplete, and type the expression
2. Copy the case block and paste it enough times to cover all the enum constants (actually, I just paste more than I need and delete later, rather than counting)
3. Move the cursor to before the first constant placeholder
4. Press TAB, then the first letter of the constant, then Enter to accept the first autocomplete suggestion
5. Repeat TAB, letter, ENTER for the rest. Autocomplete won't suggest constants you've already used in the switch, so the list narrows with each use.

Of course, it really helps if all the constants start with the same letter. In your case, consider naming them:

```
typedef enum {
    dayOfWeekSunday,
    dayOfWeekMonday,
    dayOfWeekTuesday,
    dayOfWeekWednesday,
    dayOfWeekThursday,
    dayOfWeekFriday,
    dayOfWeekSaturday
} enumDayOfWeek;
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not using Xcode, but you can very quickly burp out processed snippets with any scripting language. Throw it as a plugin in your favourite text editor too (e.g `Textmate`).

I have a `~/bin` folder which i place helpers like this and `chmod +x` them so i can use anytime like this:

`enumify.pl ~/tmp.txt`

or even better use the command line pasteboard tools:

`pbpaste | enumify.pl`

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

#enumify.pl

#reads from STDIN or use filename as first arg
#on OS X combine with pbpaste e.g pbpaste | enumify.pl

sub  trim { my $s = shift; $s =~ s/^\s+|\s+$//g; return $s };

my @lines;

$filename = $ARGV[0];

if (length($filename) > 0) {

    { local *FILE; open FILE, "<$filename"; @lines = <FILE>; close FILE }

} else {

    @lines = <STDIN>;
}   


if (scalar @lines) {

    my $target = "switch(<#switchvar#>) {\n";

    my $enumlock = 0;

    foreach (@lines) {

        if ($enumlock == 0 && m/enum/) {
            $enumlock = 1;
        }
        elsif ( $enumlock == 1) {

            $_ = trim($_);

            if (!(m/[{}]/) && (length($_)>0)) {
                $_ =~ s/,//;
                $target = "$target case $_:\nbreak;\n";
            }
        }
    }

    $target = "$target default:\nbreak;\n}\n";

    if ( $enumlock == 1) {
        print $target;
    }

}
```

It turns

```
typedef enum {
    Sunday,
    Monday,
    Tuesday,
    Wednesday,
    Thursday,
    Friday,
    Saturday
} DayOfWeek;
```

into

```
switch(<#switchvar#>) {
    case Sunday:
        break;
    case Monday:
        break;
    case Tuesday:
        break;
    case Wednesday:
        break;
    case Thursday:
        break;
    case Friday:
        break;
    case Saturday:
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hey I made an Xcode 8 Source Editor Extension for that in Swift.

https://github.com/timaktimak/SwitchCaseGenerator

[image]

Hope it is helpful!

Answer (score 1):

You can just right click the switch case itself and select `Refactor > Expand Switch Cases` and Xcode will fill in all cases that match the option. Confirmed working in Xcode version 12.0.

Answer (score 1):

As of Xcode 13 (I think) it's finally built in!

Just start typing `switch yourEnumName`, and while you're in the middle of typing `yourEnumNa...` look for the autocomplete ellipsis:

[image: Swift Switch Autocomplete]

I missed it at first because if you type the entire name, the top result becomes something else, leaving you to do things manually.